# rails_to for a duplicate record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following works fine in console and does what I want (the first line would do it, the others were just to simulate the changes. Actually it was real, those were the only changes needed):

```
irb(main):012:0> year = Year.find(678).dup
  Year Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "years".* FROM "years" WHERE "years"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "years"."year_date" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 678], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Year id: nil, year_date: "1905-09-01", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, resto: false, resid: true, file_basename: nil, person_id: 86, location_id: 95, title: "Resident", notes: "", resto_name: "", aws_url: nil, from_where_url: nil, caption: nil, croatian: true, from_where: nil, doc_id: 66>
irb(main):013:0> year.location_id = 211
=> 211
irb(main):014:0> year.resto = true
=> true
irb(main):015:0> year.resid = false
=> false
irb(main):016:0> year.title = "Co-proprietor"
=> "Co-proprietor"
irb(main):017:0> year.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Location Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 211], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Person Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 86], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Doc Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "docs".* FROM "docs" WHERE "docs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 66], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Year Create (5.3ms)  INSERT INTO "years" ("year_date", "created_at", "updated_at", "resto", "resid", "person_id", "location_id", "title", "notes", "resto_name", "croatian", "doc_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["year_date", "1905-09-01"], ["created_at", "2020-05-10 15:12:37.102224"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-10 15:12:37.102224"], ["resto", true], ["resid", false], ["person_id", 86], ["location_id", 211], ["title", "Co-proprietor"], ["notes", ""], ["resto_name", ""], ["croatian", true], ["doc_id", 66]]
   (40.9ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

I, of course, would do the changes in an `edit` or `new` page. I just want that page created with a duplicate of the information from the `show` page I'm on. Use case is creating a bunch of record and many are almost duplicates, but does need to be done manually because there is no pattern to the information that changes.

I've created various buttons, but nothing works

`<%= link_to 'Duplicate this connection (FIXME)', new_year_path(@year.dup), action: dup %>`

with:

```
def dup
  @year = Year.find(params[:id]).dup
end
```

Another iteration: `<%= link_to 'Duplicate this connection (FIXME)', edit_year_path(@year.dup) %>
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"years", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`

I'm lost on this, but probably not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `#.dup` on an ActiveRecord model object, which you're doing here, it copies over all attributes except for `id` and the base timestamps. What this means is that you have an unpersisted object. This is why you are getting the exception messages you are getting.

Assuming you want to duplicate record 678, let's say, I'd expect a path like this:

```
/years/new?base_id=678
```

In the above, `base_id=678` is a query string parameter.

You'd generate it like this:

```
<%= link_to "Duplicate", new_year_path(base_id: @year&.id) %>
```

(assuming `@year` is initialized, of course)

Then, in your controller action:

```rb
def new
  @year = Year.find_by(id: params[:base_id])&.dup || Year.new
end
```

Assuming we find the `Year` record in question, we duplicate it. Otherwise, we fall back to a new `Year` object and life is fine.

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go. Looks straightforward. And thank you for the tutorial; I'll look at it more carefully tomorrow.

Comment: I would really opt for creating a separate method in the controller instead of shoehorning this into the existing new action.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I thought it would be simple, but it's not. You've packed a lot in there. `@year&.id` and the `||` in the controller. If it's linked from `new_year_path` the first statement is `false` and then selects the `Year.new`? I read about what the `&` but will take me a while to understand it. Black and Leo spend a page explaining it. Thank you and Amit for answering. Both Amit and I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Search the record for which you want to duplicate, call `attributes` to get all attributes key-value, discard timestamp columns and pass it to `create` method to create record.

```rb
def dup
  year = Year.find(params[:id])

  @year = Year.create!(year.attributes.except("created_at", "updated_at"))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :years do
  get :duplicate
end
```

```
class Year < ApplicationRecord
  # creates a new instance of year with a a subset of the attributes
  # @return [Year] 
  def duplicate
    # attributes returns a hash with string keys 
    whitelist = %w( foo bar baz )
    self.class.new(attributes.slice(*whitelist))
  end
end
```

```
class YearsController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  # GET /years/:id/duplicate 
  def duplicate
    @year = Year.find(:id).duplicate 
    render :new
  end

  # ...
end
```

Its probably a good idea to whitelist the attributes you want to copy instead of blacklisting.

Comment: max, Thank  you for offering an alternate approach. Conceptually simpler than @Andrew's approach. And closer to what I was trying; although I would have never gotten there.